# Require argument if unknown type is not undefined

Tags: typescript

How can I type a function that optionally has a second parameter *if* it's event's data is not undefined?

For example:

```
type Events = {
  a: { bc: number }
  d: undefined
}

type Fn<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = <E extends keyof T>(event: E, data: T[E]) => void

const fn: Fn<Events> = getFN();
```

When someone calls `fn('a')` Typescript will correctly throw an error because `{ bc: number }` wasn't supplied. However, `fn('d')` will throw an error because typescript is expecting `fn('d', undefined)`.

How do I drop the requirement to supply `undefined` for `fn('d')`?

Comment: `undefined` and optional are related but not the same.  If you want to do this you programmatically you need to refactor so that the `data` parameter is either optional or required depending on `T[E]`.  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5VDN) could work. Do you want me to write that up as an answer? Or is there something else you need?

Comment: @jcalz If you do I'll mark correct, thanks!

Comment: I'll do it when I get a chance, maybe in a few hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function parameter is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters), then it will accept `undefined` as a value.  But the converse is not necessarily true; just because a function parameter accepts `undefined` it doesn't mean it's optional.  If you want an `undefined` type for `T[E]` to make `data` an optional parameter, then your `Fn` type needs to be made more complicated; the function parameters themselves need to depend on `T[E]` and not just their types.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type Fn<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = <E extends keyof T>(
  event: E, ...rest: undefined extends T[E] ? [data?: T[E]] : [data: T[E]]
) => void
```

Now the `Fn` type is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function whose first parameter is of type `E`, and after that the [array of the rest of the parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments) is of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on `T[E]`.

Let's examine that conditional type: `undefined extends T[E] ? [data?: T[E]] : [data: T[E]]`. So if the property type `T[E]` accepts `undefined`, then the rest of the parameters list is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) with a single [optional element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) with a [label](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) `data`.  If the property type `T[E]` does *not* accept `undefined`, then the rest of the parameters list is a tuple with a single *required* element, also labeled `data`.  That means no matter what, we're building a two-parameter function type, but if `T[E]` accepts undefined, the second parameter will be optional.

---

Let's try it out:

```
declare const fn: Fn<Events>;

fn('a'); // error, expected 2 elements, got 1
/* const fn: <"a">(event: "a", data: {  bc: number; }) => void */

fn('a', { bc: 123 }); // okay

fn('d') // okay
/* const fn: <"d">(event: "d", data?: undefined) => void */
```

That all behaves as expected. When you use [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) to observe the type of `fn('a', ...)`, you see that it has two parameters, the second of which is named `data`, required, and of type `{bc: number}`.  When you call `fn('d', ...)`, on the other hand, the second parameter is also named `data`, but's optional and of type `undefined`.  So now you get errors where and only where you expect.

If the type passed to `Fn` has an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), this will automatically become an optional `data` parameter of the same type:

```
declare const o: Fn<{ opt?: string }>
o('opt', "str"); // okay
o('opt'); // also okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gWAFBRQCGAXNlAEYDGZiArgLYUQBOUAvvoQCZl2LcIAMwCWiCN3yc8+UJCgAxRAB4AKlAgAPYEm5oAShCoB7Ft2UpgLMQHMANFH4BrRMYDuiAHyeMUZTA1tXTQnCBBjIShVTwAKLg0EZDIYBwA6dJYISz4BYTEJQJ0BNFUAbRgAXSgAfihS7iJgImqyMsqqsnrG0ijyioqASgwfOGMRSRk8QSoAGyJMqBNESyghRDIlf0TUTwBufHw1mIByImOB3agAeiuNFhZTBy1IKh1uKAAmDRmIBiRUBw2YzAKAARnwVwAVItjMsQWsyMoAEREJGxCDbMgopEOBpNMhYQjUWiMZgsS7sIboEZjd6Qq4HPBHU7HByE4lgj4AZg4F2ut2MTiIIEZzO4535UEFwoh0KWKwRfiR3DRMQx-yxKtx3RajlyonE3CpNPGUHpjOmcwW8pBxg2KkJxjAwF1lmsiBsHE8+GMJydwFZUCRbqRfJuUqFIrwvuO-vOl3DRBmKGMEeFQA)